Should I move this question and its answers (somehow) to Unix & Linux?
This question was just closed because it "does not appear to be about a ... software tools primarily used by programmers".
I gather from this meta discussion that "tools primarily used by programmers" now excludes things like tar, less, SSH, Git etc.  Possibly only things like IDEs and text editors are tools allowed on Stack Overflow.
So is Unix & Linux the right place now?  Is there a way for me to migrate the question and the answers?

You won't be able to move it, only a moderator would be able to. I, personally, don't see the need for migration; it could be left in its current state for "historical significance".

Also questions about tar, less, ssh, and git aren't off-topic on [so] if the question is programmatical. SSH isn't solely or mostly used by developers (my usage of SSH is never programmatical) , so a question just on SSH wouldn't be on topic (and I doubt it would have been back in 2013 tbh).

Sure.  If I asked the question today, it would be rapidly closed and I'd re-ask at Unix & Linux before a bunch of good answers accumulated, I guess.  If it were moved to Unix & Linux with a breadcrumb bouncing to it, would it make the useful answers less findable or is that not mechanically straightforward in StackExchange?

This probably depends somewhat on whether this would be a duplicate over on U&L.SE; if the info and similar answers already exist over there, then the rigmarole of migration may not be worth it

There is only this, as far as I can find. @zcoop98

The linked question is too old (>60 days) for a normal migration (I say "normal" because some time ago the mods found a way to migrate old questions)

"I gather from this meta discussion that "tools primarily used by programmers" now excludes things like tar, less, SSH, Git etc." I think you learned the wrong lesson. Tools aren't on or off topic, questions about them are. What matters is whether you are doing a programming-like task, using the tool. Questions about IDEs are on topic because they're questions about using them to write code. You would scarcely use them for anything else. A question about the tar command is unlikely to pass muster, but a question about reading and interpreting tar archives certainly could.

@KarlKnechtel "Questions about IDEs are on topic because they're questions about using them to write code" - the on-topic questions would be. But there are also questions about failing to install one, or on changing the theme. Are those on-topic, having nothing to do with the act of programming? That's where opinions start to differ.

You can't move the question because it's too old to migrate; only questions less than 60 days old can be migrated, including by moderators. There could be a way for a staff member to move it, but I don't know that they've ever done that, and I doubt it would be worth the trouble to do that here.
The question doesn't necessarily need to have anything happen to it; it's not at risk of being deleted, so it will remain here as a resource (and remain as a notice to viewers that such questions should not be newly asked on Stack Overflow today).
